# Column sums between $2$ and $3$

Tags: combinatorics

> In a table with four columns, every cell has a nonnegative real number and the numbers in each column sum to $5$. Suppose that every row contains at least two numbers $\le 1$. Can we always find a set of rows such that among the four column sums in those rows, the two smallest are $\leq 3$ and the two largest are $\geq 2$?

This is true in the case of two rows: each row contains two numbers $\leq 1$, so if the condition does not hold for the first row, the two largest numbers are $<2$. But then the second row contains two numbers $\leq 1$ and two numbers $\geq 3$, so the condition holds for the second row.

Comment: how about a table of all 0.5 (which would give 10 rows in total)

Comment: @Dubs Then taking any $4$, $5$ or $6$ rows works.